# Angular 5 - Dynamic Row Addition clears the selection in Table

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular4-forms, angular5

I am new to Angular and I am playing around with Some of the Angular Features. 
While exploring Two way binding, I have created a Table with dynamic Row addition on the click of a button. 
I observed that the selection of the other rows gets cleared the moment I add a New Row, after a bit of trial and error, I found out the culprit was `<form>`and when I removed the tag it was working correctly. I have included the `FormModule` into the NGModule imports and i still see the same behaviour.

Can someone please explain how do i use table inside a `<form>` without this error. An explanation of why is this happening is also much appreciated.

Please find my created Plunker below

> https://plnkr.co/edit/5YPn88pNOhVoPJA8kSBj?p=preview

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is not with the `form` but the `input names`

`name` should be different,

What you can do is add `index` in `loop` and then change `name="soc1"` to `name="soc1{{i}}"`

Here's the Solution :

```
<tr *ngFor="let dat of arr; let i=index;">
    <td>
        <select name="soc1{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="dat.it">
            <option value="PP">PP</option>
            <option value="PQ">PQ</option>
          </select>
    </td>
    <td> <select name="soc2{{i}}{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="dat.bit">
            <option value="PP">PP</option>
            <option value="PQ">PQ</option>
          </select></td>
    <td><button name="Name" (click)="addRow()">Add</button></td>
</tr>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/K14JvpIb6a74cOcvxPob?p=preview)**

Comment: Thank you for this..Just one question though, why did it work outside the form and did not work inside the form tag? Why is there a difference in behavior?

Comment: Outside form it doen't care about the input name they all treated differently.